# JDBC COUNT() a certain row how to get the result

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am very new to JDBC and I am practicing executing query's and statements.

```
try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS \"Number of suppliers\", city\r\n" + 
                    "FROM supplier\r\n" + 
                    "GROUP BY city\r\n" + 
                    "ORDER BY city DESC\r\n";
            //st.executeUpdate(query);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);  

            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("supplierNum"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("city"));
                space();
            }   

        st.close();
        conn.close();

        }
```

I am trying to execute and print the results using `SELECT COUNT(supplierNum) AS "Number of suplliers", cityFROM supplierGROUP BY city ORDER BY city DESC;`

The console just terminate and nothing happens no error message nothing just a blank screen.

This is the table I am trying to access

```
CREATE TABLE supplier 
(
    supplierNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    status TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (supplierNum)
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to just get the count, or are you trying to loop over the rows and print out the data? In SQL, COUNT() is considered an aggregate function,  and you cannot simply use it and select other columns (name, status, etc.) in the same statement without grouping or similar.

Comment: @KellyM Not true in the case of using `COUNT()` as an analytic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aliased the count column as `"Number of suplliers"`, yet your JDBC code is trying to find `supplierNum`.  Use consistent aliases everywhere to resolve this problem:

```
String query = "SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS supplierCnt " + 
               "FROM supplier " + 
               "GROUP BY city " + 
               "ORDER BY city DESC";

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); 

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("supplierCnt"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("city"));
    space();
}
```